# Power series convergence with $x^2$ instead of $x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I find the interval in which these series converge?

$$\sum 2^{-n} \cdot (x^2 - 1)^n$$

Comment: Tried D'Alembert's ratio test?

Comment: set $X=\frac{x^2-1}{2}$

Comment: Your title is approximate, should be $x^2-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Find the interval in which

$$\sum2^{-n}t^n$$ converges and solve $x^2-1\in(a,b)$ for $x$.

Comment: Could also be a closed interval, I am not telling you.

Comment: What I got is (-sqrt(3), sqrt(3)) by solving x^2 - 1 for x and setting the interval with (- r + x0, r + x0)